# Fine uniformity on a set

Tags: uniform-spaces

I came across the term fine uniformity while reading a paper.
I want to know

> What is meant by fine uniformity on a set? Is this the largest uniformity that can be defined on it? That is, uniformity containning diagonal of the set?

Comment: my guess is that the term fine uniformity applies to a uniformity on a topological space. The same (given, fixed) topology could be generated by different uniformities, and among these uniformities there is a finest one (containing the most entourages, compatible with the given topology). There are certain conditions guaranteeing that a finest uniformity exists, since it doesn't always exist.

Comment: When asking for the definition of a term found "while reading a paper," it is helpful to Readers to cite the paper (title, author, journal or website of publication).

Answer (score 3):

A topological space is uniformizable if and only if it is [completely regular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tychonoff_space). 
One can show that, on a completely regular space, there is a finest uniformity compatible with the topology, called the *fine uniformity*.

The fine uniformity is generated by all open neighborhoods $D$ of the diagonal of $X \times X$ (with the product topology) such that there exists a sequence $(D_n)_{n \geqslant 0}$ of open neighborhoods of the diagonal such that $D = D_0$ and $D_{n+1}\circ D_{n+1}\subseteq D_n$ for all $n$. See the wikipedia entry [uniformizable space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniformizable_space) for more details.

In contrast, every topological space is quasi-uniformizable (the definition of a quasi-uniformity is the same as that of a uniformity, except that the inverse of an entourage is not required to be an entourage).